# how to use void ** pointer correctly?

Tags: c, void-pointers

I am trying to use a double `void` pointer but I am a little bit confused about the usage.
I have a `struct` that contains a `void **` array.

```
struct Thing{
    void ** array;
};

struct Thing * c = malloc (sizeof(struct Thing));
c->array = malloc( 10 * sizeof(void *) );
```

So If I want to assign a different object to each pointer and try to retrieve the value

```
 // Option 1
 *(c->array + index) = (void *) some_object_ptr;

 // Option 2
 c->array[index] = (void *) some_object_ptr;
```

then, I have another function that gives `(void *) item` that points to each cell,  not the `some_object_ptr`.

If I want to retrieve the value which pointed to by `some_object_ptr`,
should I do

```
 function return type is 'void *' and takes argument 'void *'
 // Option 3 
 return (void**) item

 // Option 4
 return *((void**)item)?
```

the weird thing is that when I used array the array subscript method I couldn't use  option 4, only option 3; and when I used `*(c->array + index)` I could only use opt.4. and not opt.3. ..

Can anyone please tell me about this? If I am making any invalid assumptions, then could you please correct me?

Comment: Maybe he needs it?

Comment: Also, options 3 and 4 are not the same, 3 returns a `void**` and 4 returns a `void*`. And what exactly is `item`?

Comment: "then, I have another function that gives (void * item) that points to each cell, not the 'some_object_ptr'." <- what kinda cell? It's returning the address of some_object_ptr?

Comment: at Kevin, sorry I just edited

Comment: so assume it is a function that returns poinere to the object that is pointed by some_object_ptr and it takes void * as an argument that points to the cell of array

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A `void **` is just a pointer to a pointer to memory with an unspecified type. You can only dereference it once (since you can't dereference a `void *`). However, apart from that, it is basically like any other pointer type. If it helps you, think of it the same way as you would with `int *`.

So, in your specific situation, we have:

```
void** array;
int arrayLen = 10;
array = (void**)malloc(arrayLen * sizeof(void*));

some_type_t* some_object_ptr;    
// The following two assignment are equivalent since in C,
// array[index] <=> *(array + index)
array[index] = (void*)some_object_ptr;
*(array + index) = (void*)some_object_ptr;
```

Then `array` is a pointer to the whole array, while `*array` is a pointer to the first element, since it is equivalent to `array[0]`.

Comment: It depend what you want to return. Do you want to return the first element in the array or the array. If you had an `int* array;`, would  you do `return array;` or `return array[0];`? This will be the same here.

Comment: I want to return what is in the cell, which I think is the void pointer that points to another object and returning part is in different function that it does not know the index. Instead it is given void * item which points to the cell that contains the void pointer

Comment: Don't forget to check if the malloc was actually valid.

right after the assignment, you should check with something like this:
    `if(array == NULL) return;`

Answer (score 2):

One quick hint about pointers: if you are casting it, you are probably doing something wrong.

As for your question. I am not sure what `item` is in your problem. In your first part you've already discovered how to acces a member in your array. You could simply use it:

```
void *get_item(Thing *c, int index)
{
    return *(c->array + index); // or return c->array[index];
}
```

If you need the address of the pointer at index:

```
void **get_item_cell(Thing *c, int index)
{
    return c->array + index; // or return &c->array[index];
}
```

In the second part, you don't dereference the pointer (for + option), or take the address of array result, since it automatically dereferences it.

---

EDIT:
I think I now know what you want. You have a function similar to my second one above, but it is:

```
void *get_item_cell(Thing *c, int index)
{
    return (void *)(c->array + index);
}
```

You want to dereference the value returned from this function, and access the object. In that case, you can only use Option 4 safely. Since you don't have the index, you cannot move to any other cell (you don't know if you are at the end of the array, or at the beginning - so no additions or subtractions). You can only fix the mistake of the above function: cast to `void **`, and then dereference it: `*(void **)item`. This will give you a `void *`. If you want to access the object pointed from this cell, you need to cast that to the correct type as well: `some_object_ptr *obj = *(void**)item`.

Comment: oh, so returning part is in different function that it does not know the index and void * item points to the array of cell

Comment: Only my understanding of what you want to do. If you have the address of the pointee (an object in the array), and want to return to either the index or the cell of the array, you'll have to loop through each cell, check if the pointee is the same object as the one you want, then return the relevant information when it is. If this is what you want, I can add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The fact you are working with `void*` and `void**` doesn't matter, pointer arithmetic still works fine, so both options you wrote are correct.

Here's an example:

```
struct Thing
{
    void ** array;
};

struct Object
{
    int i;
    char c;
};

int main ()
{

    struct Thing * c = malloc (sizeof(struct Thing));
    c->array = malloc(10 * sizeof(void*));

    struct Object * o = malloc (sizeof(struct Object));
    o->i = 2; o->c = 'a';

    *(c->array + 2) = o;

    printf("Object: i = %d, c = %c\n", ((Object*)c->array[2])->i, ((Object*)c->array[2])->c);

    free(o);
    free(c->array);
    free(c);
    return 0;
}
```

Since it's `void*` you can put there pointer to whatever, just don't forget it to cast to original type before using it ;)

Comment: You DO NOT have to cast malloc()'s return value. C standard explicitly says that void * is compatible with *any* pointer type. Several respectful C programmers, for example Linus Torvalds, and enterprises such as GNU argue against this casting and call it bad practice as it decreases readability.

Comment: Also, pointer arithmetic is NOT the same as with integers. AFAIK GCC assumes void * to be a byte ptr, and, for example, on a 32-bit system, int is 4 bytes, so (int *)ptr + 1 will give a different memory address from that of (void *)ptr + 1 would.

Comment: Sorry, I'm used to work with Microsoft Visual Studio even when I code in C. Compiler won't let me write malloc without casting it's return value... I edited my answer

Comment: @user529758 I say http://bigthink.com/videos/why-the-programming-language-c-is-obsolete

Answer (score -1):

Almighty push!

```
any_type x ;
void * v = * ( void * * ) & x ;
```

almighty pull!

```
void * v ;
any_type x = * ( any_type * ) & v ;
```

beware of losing/gaining digits

Comment: What purpose does `void *v = *(void **) &x;` serve beyond `void *v = &x;`? The cast and dereference of `&x` does nothing. A *memory address* has no type to begin with.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: One could trick around this way C's limitation not allowing to assign a function-pointer's value to a `void`-pointer.

Comment: Just a fun with * ( void * * ) & , a tricky way to cast any type into a void* and viceversa... nothing serious wrt the question, I've deserved the -1 :)

Comment: @Fabio This is undefined behavior and could make your computer grow legs and crawl away. Use `memcpy` for implementation-defined behavior, which is partially better.